# How do you write loops in awk without them affecting each other?

Tags: awk

My script outputs a grocery list (col $1)  with prices (col $3)
Then it combines them by category (column $2) and adds the cost of each category.

The problem is when I run my for loop it always messes with only the first line of the original grocery list output. 
I tried separating them in a different begin end but it doesn't work.

Here's my current code the loop with sub categories is commented out.

```
    #!/bin/awk
    BEGIN { FS="\t+"; OFS=" "; printf("%-30s %s\n", "Item","Cost") 
printf("%-30s %s\n", "====","====")}
{ printf("%-30s %s\n", $2, $3, 30) }


END {
}

#BEGIN {
#}

#NR==1{print;next}
#{a[$1]+=substr($3, 2)}


#END { for(i in a)printf("%-30s %s\n", i, a[i], 30)  
#}
```

Output sample:

```
Item                          Cost
====                          ======
Air freshener                 $10.60
Antiperspirant / Deodorant    $03.80
Apples                        $10.80
Asparagus                     $01.05
Avocados                      $08.25
BBQ sauce                     $08.55
Baby food                     $08.60
Baby wash                     $05.40

Subtotal by Category       
---------------------------
Alcohol             $ 76.10
Baby/Pet            $ 81.55
Baking              $ 54.15
Bread               $ 50.20
Canned goods        $ 55.60
Chips/Crackers      $ 53.65
Cleaner/Detergent   $ 46.75
Condiments          $ 92.40
Dairy               $ 46.30
Produce             $195.45
Soap/Sundry         $113.65
Spices              $ 89.40
===========================
Total               $955.20
```

Input Sample:

```
Cleaner/Detergent   Air freshener   $10.60
Soap/Sundry Antiperspirant / Deodorant  $03.80
Produce Apples  $10.80
Produce Asparagus   $01.05
Produce Avocados    $08.25
Condiments  BBQ sauce   $08.55
Baby/Pet    Baby food   $08.60
Baby/Pet    Baby wash   $05.40
Bread   Bagels / Croissants $10.35
Baking  Baking powder / Soda    $07.85
Produce Bananas $02.90
Spices  Basil   $01.70
Soap/Sundry Bath soap / Hand soap   $06.75
Cleaner/Detergent   Bathroom cleaner    $04.55
```

Comment: without sample input and expected output - it's hard to understand what do you want to achieve

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've added some sample input and output, thanks.

Comment: why have `Bathroom cleaner`, `Bagels / Croissants` and others been missed from the output?

Comment: And how do you get a subtotal of $195.45 for Produce when the total of all of the inputs is far less than that. Obviously you need to make sure the expected output you provide is the output expected from the input you provide, not the output from some other input otherwise how will we know when we test a possible solution against your input if the output it produces is correct or not?

Comment: The actual list is over 100  items long so I posted samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GNU** **awk** solution that will do what you want in one go:

```
$ cat tst.awk
#!/bin/awk
BEGIN {
    FS="\t+";OFS="   "
}
NF==3{                                               # check if there are fields
    amount=substr($3,2)
    l1=length($1); l2=length($2)                     # save max length of 1st col
    col1=(l1<l2)?(col1<l2?l2:col1):(col1<l1?l1:col1) # in col1     

    a[$2]=($2 in a? a[$2]+amount : amount)           # item as key, amount as value
    total=total+amount                               # save total, for col2 width
    c[$1]=c[$1]+amount                               # save sum per category
}
END {
    col2=length(total)                               # determine col2 width

    printf "%-*s%s%s\n", col1, "Item", OFS, "Cost"   # print header item table
    printf "%s%s%s\n", separator("=",col1), OFS, separator("=",col2+2) 

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"             # define sorting order

    for(i in a)                                      # print Item table
        printf "%-*s%s$ %*.2f\n", col1, i, OFS, col2, a[i]    

    printf "\n%s\n", "Subtotal by Category"          # print header category table
    print separator("-", col1+col2+length(OFS)+2)    # "+2" because of "$ "

    for (j in c)                                     # print category table
        printf "%-*s%s$ %*.2f\n", col1, j, OFS, col2, c[j]    

    print separator("=", col1+col2+length(OFS)+2)    # "+2" because of "$ "
    printf "%-*s%s$ %*.2f\n", col1, "Total", OFS, col2, total # print total
}
func separator(sep,n){                               # function for generating
    s=sprintf("%*s",n,""); gsub(/ /,sep,s); return s # separator line
}
```

With provided input it generates:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
Item                         Cost
==========================   =======
Air freshener                $ 10.60
Antiperspirant / Deodorant   $  3.80
Apples                       $ 10.80
Asparagus                    $  1.05
Avocados                     $  8.25
BBQ sauce                    $  8.55
Baby food                    $  8.60
Baby wash                    $  5.40
Bagel / Croissants           $ 10.35
Baking powder / Soda         $  7.85
Bananas                      $  2.90
Basil                        $  1.70
Bath soap / Hand soap        $  6.75
Bathroom cleaner             $  4.55

Subtotal by Category
------------------------------------
Baby/Pet                     $ 14.00
Baking                       $  7.85
Bread                        $ 10.35
Cleaner/Detergent            $ 15.15
Condiments                   $  8.55
Produce                      $ 23.00
Soap/Sundry                  $ 10.55
Spices                       $  1.70
====================================
Total                        $ 91.15
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the documentation too!

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you first get the data (using GNU awk for gensub() and \S/\s- with other awks use a variable + [g]sub() + [:space:]):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    cat = $1
    item = gensub(/^\S+\s+|\s+\S+$/,"","g")
    cost = gensub(/\$/,"",1,$NF)
    print "Item", item, cost
    subTot[cat] += cost
    tot += cost
}
END {
    for (cat in subTot) {
        print "Category", cat, subTot[cat]
    }
    print "Total", "Total", tot
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Item    Air freshener   10.60
Item    Antiperspirant / Deodorant      03.80
Item    Apples  10.80
Item    Asparagus       01.05
Item    Avocados        08.25
Item    BBQ sauce       08.55
Item    Baby food       08.60
Item    Baby wash       05.40
Item    Bagels / Croissants     10.35
Item    Baking powder / Soda    07.85
Item    Bananas 02.90
Item    Basil   01.70
Item    Bath soap / Hand soap   06.75
Item    Bathroom cleaner        04.55
Category        Spices  1.7
Category        Baby/Pet        14
Category        Condiments      8.55
Category        Produce 23
Category        Soap/Sundry     10.55
Category        Baking  7.85
Category        Bread   10.35
Category        Cleaner/Detergent       15.15
Total   Total   91.15
```

and then you can read that into a spreadsheet and/or write whatever formatting script you like to provide a layout, e.g.:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file |
  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1!=p{print "_" ORS $1, "Cost" ORS "====", "===="; p=$1} {print $2, "$"$3}' |
  column -s$'\t' -t
_
Item                        Cost
====                        ====
Air freshener               $10.60
Antiperspirant / Deodorant  $03.80
Apples                      $10.80
Asparagus                   $01.05
Avocados                    $08.25
BBQ sauce                   $08.55
Baby food                   $08.60
Baby wash                   $05.40
Bagels / Croissants         $10.35
Baking powder / Soda        $07.85
Bananas                     $02.90
Basil                       $01.70
Bath soap / Hand soap       $06.75
Bathroom cleaner            $04.55
_
Category                    Cost
====                        ====
Spices                      $1.7
Baby/Pet                    $14
Condiments                  $8.55
Produce                     $23
Soap/Sundry                 $10.55
Baking                      $7.85
Bread                       $10.35
Cleaner/Detergent           $15.15
_
Total                       Cost
====                        ====
Total                       $91.15
```